# Add edit/delete button at the end of the table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I've inline create of row in table in my index view.when user click on add row button it pre-append new editable row to the table .

at the end of the row there is button for save the data of the new row.when user click on save I disable the textboxes and checkboxes and

remove the button of create, what I need is instead add to this row the button of edit and delete, which is default for all table rows, how should I do that?

Here is the code for disable the row fields:

```
//Hide the create button
$('#btnsubmit').remove();
//Change the name property to disabled
$('input').attr('readonly', true);
$('#name').css("border", "none");
```

Here is the defult button for all the rows(if i press on create and refresh the page I will see the  button also in this new saved row but I want to

add them when the row is added and the page was not refreshed...

```
   <td>
       @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
       @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
   </td>
```

This is how I add the new row with the create button when user click on create new row

```
var html = '<tr><td>@Html.TextBox("name")</td><td>@Html.CheckBox("checkBox1")</td><td>@Html.CheckBox("checkBox2")</td><td>@Html.CheckBox("checkBox3")</td><td><input id="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" /></td><td></tr>';

    function addRow() {

        if ($('#btnsubmit').length == 0) {

            //Append new row to the table
            jQuery(html).prependTo('#data-table');
```

**UPDATE**
this is the example of the table which for every row there is edit/delete button

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

I try to add the following but the button is not added when click on create

```
 $('#btnsubmit').click(function () {

                $.post("/Roles/Create", { name : $("name").val() }, function(NewID){

                    var oTD = $("#btnsubmit").parent();
                    oTD.append("<a href='/Roles/Edit/"+ NewID +"'>Edit</a>");

                    oTD.append("<a href='/Roles/Delete/"+ NewID +"'>Delete</a>");


                });
```

Comment: Not able to understand your question

Comment: @RashminJaviya-please see my update ,if its not help please let me know what you dont understand and I will explain ...

Comment: *what I need is instead add to this row the button of edit and delete, which is default for all table rows* what do you mean by this

Comment: @RashminJaviya-please see my updated post let me know if you have any qustion...

Comment: Does the save button postback the page or you manage through ajax?

Comment: @RashminJaviya-please see my updated post let me know if you have any qustion...the only differ from the defult asp table is that when you click on create new instead of navigating to other page in my program its create new empty editable row with save button...

Comment: @RashminJaviya- i use ajax...

Comment: @RashminJaviya- do you need additinal info?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54936/discussion-between-rashmin-javiya-and-mileyh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to return the ID in response of ajax call and add append anchor with the returned ID

```
function SaveData()
{
    $.post("/[Controllar]/Savedata", { firstname : $("txtFirst").val(), lastname : $("txtLast").val() }, function(NewID){

        var oTD = $("#btnsubmit").parent();
        oTD.append("<a href='/[ControllarName]/Edit/"+ NewID +"'>Edit</a>");
        oTD.append("<a href='/[ControllarName]/Detail/"+ NewID +"'>Detail</a>");
        oTD.append("<a href='/[ControllarName]/Delete/"+ NewID +"'>Delete</a>");

        //Hide the create button
        $('#btnsubmit').remove();
        //Change the name property to disabled
        $('input').attr('readonly', true);
        $('#name').css("border", "none");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rashmin,I try with your code but nothing happen (I adopt the code for my model which have name property and controller name is roles),any idea what is missing?voted up for the support!Please see the post update 2

Comment: Thank you very much its working great!I've addtional question which I post now please see if you have time to help\